# Ansible - how to run Java jar with parameters?

Tags: linux, bash, vagrant, ansible

I have a problem with ansible playbook. I am trying to run a Java jar as a command. Whenever I run this directly on the virtual machine - it works all the time:

```
java -jar Installer20161018.jar -readImage Linux_x86-64_20161111.zip -installDir /opt/installPath/vf5511/instDir
```

**important information:** the installation HAS to be run from user `vf5511`, and his `home` folder is `/opt/installPath/vf5511`

But when trying to write a playbook and run it - it gets all wrong.

This is the playbook:

```
---
- hosts: webmwc10
  become: yes
  become_user: wm5511
  become_method: sudo
  tasks:
    - name: installing server
      shell: java -jar Installer20161018.jar -readImage Linux_x86-64_20161111.zip -installDir /opt/installPath/vf5511/instDir
```

When I run the playbook, I get an error:

```
"rc": 127,
"start": "2017-06-02 09:21:31.931049",
"stderr": "/bin/sh: java: command not found",
"stderr_lines": [
    "/bin/sh: java: command not found"
],
"stdout": "",
"stdout_lines": []
```

Java not found? I don't understand this. Java is installed and working properly!

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: The JDK/JRE's `bin` dir probably isn't found in the `$PATH` of that user. One workaround would be to use an absolute path to the `java` executable instead of relying on the `$PATH`, but I don't know what would be the best practice in term of `Ansible` scripts.

Comment: how did you install Java ? sounds like JAVA_HOME is not set, you can check https://stackoverflow.com/a/31775587/4296747 to set correctly the env variables

Comment: You can also provide the environment variables (such as PATH) in the `environment` keyword on the play: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_environment.html

Comment: Give the full path to java in your shell task and post back if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Run below commands on your target server to rule out Java issues

```
    which java
    java -version
```

Upon successful results add quotes to your shell command like below and run the playbook again.

```
    shell: "java -jar Installer20161018.jar -readImage Linux_x86-64_20161111.zip -installDir /opt/installPath/vf5511/instDir"
```

Comment: This would work as a check before running jar, but the question is targeted more at running jar.

Answer (score 0):

You should add your java address before "java". This problem may be occurs when using ssh too. For example:

```
shell: /your_java_address_in_target_server/java -jar Installer20161018.jar -readImage Linux_x86-64_20161111.zip -installDir /opt/installPath/vf5511/instDir
```

Answer (score 0):

#1. make sure you "become_user" who has access to java
#2. In the .bash_profile, make sure you are setting the Java home path.
#3. Before calling the java command, run .bash_profile to make sure the JDK path is set.
Eg: - name: unjar abc.jar
shell: source ~/.bash_profile; jar xvf abc.jar